# Run button is not working in android studio and it is not disabled

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I press android studio's `Run` button it is not launching the chosen device dialog and it is not running application to install also. It said JDK mismatch, unable to sync gradle after resolving that. Also, it is not running the app and not launching.

Comment: Your error log says it all... Find a way to link your project to your JDK path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the run button is not working but you're not seeing any errors (you said you resolved them), then you should check if your antivirus software has put `adb.exe` into quarantine. Happened to me twice with Avast, it's a false positive. When it happens Android Studio will not report any error but pressing the Run button will not do anything.

Comment: In android>sdk>platform tools adb.exe is not there then i placed adb.exe it works, thanks